# I need to run kubectl commands simultaneously in JAVA for different EKS clusters

Tags: java, windows, amazon-web-services, cmd, amazon-eks

I want to get data for two EKS clusters via JAVA (Different clusters in the same account or different account).
But if I run 'aws eks update-kubeconfig' command. I am able to get data for only one of them.
Can anyone suggest me a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the below steps to connect (I used processBuilder to connect to kubectl):

1. Set [AWS environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-set).
2. We can generate unique
   KUBECONFIG file for each cluster in a different name (name according
   to your feasibility) using [`--kubeconfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html) argument.
3. Invoke kubectl commands via the processbuilder object.